# Center `CustomScrollView` if has space

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I have the [folowing code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d256e88f0dff30ba127d138b4d73e963):

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(
            parent: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          ),
          controller: controller,
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 64),
                  child: Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList.builder(
              itemCount: tiles.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final text = tiles[index];
                return Card(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 24,
                    vertical: 8,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      text,
                      style: theme.textTheme.bodyLarge,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
```

This causes my layout output to be like this on my phone:

[image: Current layout]

What I wanted was a way of putting everything centred if all fit the screen, or else continue as is.

[image: Centered]

Is it possible to do anything similar with the use of `Slivers`? I wanted them because I would like that the title bounces and scrolls with the items when they're scrolled.

Comment: Have you tried shrinkwrap set to true in CustomScrollView and then wrapping the custom scroll in a Center widget?

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Please answer here so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to ListView, CustomScrollView has a shrinkWrap variable that when set to true will attempt to minimize the height of the scroll area.

The default alignment for a scaffold is top left so once you shrink wrap the scroll view you will need to add the center widget as it's parent to get the center alignment you desire. The code looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(
            parent: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          ),
          controller: controller,
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 64),
                  child: Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList.builder(
              itemCount: tiles.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final text = tiles[index];
                return Card(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 24,
                    vertical: 8,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      text,
                      style: theme.textTheme.bodyLarge,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```